# Driver updates for Dell Inspirion 5559 on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, dell

I'd like some advice as I'm going back to Linux after a while. I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 on my old Dell Inspirion 5559 and all looks and sounds good. I would like to ensure I'm on the latest hardware drivers but Dell no longer support recent versions of Ubuntu for this laptop. 'Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers' is empty (proprietary drivers for devices is enabled). The current maximum video resolution on the built in screen is only 1366 x 768, which is a little low res.

Any advice appreciated,
Jason

Comment: First step would be to figure out what video card you have and search for drivers for it.  The intel integrated video should already be supported.  If you have a discrete card, you may need to install packages.  I wouldn't recommend the proprietary driver for a card this old however.

Comment: I am afraid that no driver update will make the display grow more pixels than it has. You'll need to replace the display with a better one to get a higher resolution.